# Returning different datatype depending on the need

Tags: c++, class, matrix

I am currently implementing my own matrix data structure, one particular block of code that I have trouble dealing with is the following:

```
T& operator()(size_t x){
            if(rows == 1){
                if(x >= cols){
                    throw runtime_error("Akses indeks di luar batas.");
                } else return mat[0][x];
            } else {
                matrix<T> result(1, cols);
                for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++){
                    result(1, i) = mat[x][i];
                } 
                return result;
            }   
        }
```

This indeed looks wrong since the function returns `T` while in the else condition tries to return a `matrix<T>`.

The goal that I am trying to achieve is that when accesing `matrix1(i)` while `matrix1` is one dimensional i.e `matrix1<int> = {1, 2, 3, 4}` it will return a scalar while if `matrix2` is a 2 dimensional i.e `matrix2<int> = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` accesing `matrix2(0)` will return a 1 dimensional matrix (or a mathematical vector) that in this case is the entire first row `{1, 2, 3}`.

For example if I want to define a new matrix `mat` that is just one row of matrix1, I can just do `matrix<int> mat = matrix[1]` for example.

Also I want to have a functionality such that when I let `matrix[1]` as a parameter in a function it will pass just the row 1 in particular.

This functionality is perhaps similar to numpy array.

Thank you in advanced.

I have been stuck for quite a while with no solution.

Comment: Your `else` branch tries to return a dangling reference.

Comment: A function can only return *one* type and you cannot overload functions on return type only.

Comment: T is a 1x1 matrix of T, what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
std::variant<T, matrix<T>> operator()(size_t x) {
   if (rows == 1) {
      //...
      return std::variant<T, matrix<T>>(mat[0][x]);
   }
   else {
      matrix<T> result(1, cols);
      //...
      return std::variant<T, matrix<T>>(result);
   }
}
```

You can check if the result contains a particular value using `std::holds_alternative`, and you can access the element using `std::get`:

```
std::variant<T, matrix<T>> element = m(0); //access first element
if (std::holds_alternative<T>(element))
{
   //element returned is a scalar
   T e = std::get<T>(element); //Assumes the type T has a copy constructor
   //...
}
else
{
   //element returned is a matrix
   matrix<T> e = std::get<matrix<T>>(element); //Assumes the type 'matrix' has a copy constructor
   //...
}
```

Comment: You may want to provide a suggestion that uses `std::visit`, especially since you can leverage `if constexpr`.  Other than that, good answer.